# Color gradient in symbology in ArcGIS 10.1 for interpolation raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, interpolation, color

I have measured noise and want to create with this measured points a noise map with interpolation....is there any way in symbology to create a flowing transition between the different colors for the created interpolation raster?

I used color ramp, so the colors have a gradiation but the borders between these colors are not fluent

or in simple words: i want to have a result like a rainbow, where the colors are fluent but without recognizable borders

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As Chris W said, the first think is to make sure that your raster is a true continuous raster, but for interpolation results it should be the case. Note that you will maybe need to make your interpolated raster permanent(right click > make permanent) to gain full control of its rendering.

Then you should use the "stretch" renderer instead of the "classified" renderer for smoother transitions between colors. You can right click on any color ramp to edit it in order to have the color scheme that you want, and you can save this as a style to reuse later.

Finally, if you don't like to see the pixel, you can chose linear interpolation instead of nearest neighbour for the display properties, but this will use more ressources to display your layer.

Answer (score 0):

Really the only way to do this in raster is to re-run your interpolation using a smaller cell size and/or use more classes in your symbology.  In order to increase the smoothness of the color transition, you either need more break values to which more colors can be assigned or more resolution to the raster to allow for a longer transition (or both).  Since you are limited to 32 classes, you may also want a more limited color ramp so there are fewer colors to transition between.  You could also build your own custom ramp using a multi-part ramp to smooth out the overall ramp between colors of your choice.